# How can provide dynamically varying OR conditions for filtering dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, filter, conditional-statements

I have a `dataframe` and I use mutiple conditions to filter it.The code is kind of like below (recency.py).

```
def recency(config):
    i = config.exclude_list

    sales = pd.read_excel(config.input_path + "klm sales UPD.xlsx")


    df_exclude = sales[(sales["Product"].str.contains(i[0])==True)
                     | (sales["Product"].str.contains(i[1])==True)                     
                     | (sales["Customer"].str.contains(i[2])==True)
                     | (sales["Customer"].str.contains(i[3])==True)
                     | (sales["Customer"].str.contains(i[4])==True)
                     | (sales["Customer"].str.contains(i[5])==True)
                     | (sales["Customer"].str.contains(i[6])==True)
                     | (sales["Remarks"].str.contains(i[7])== True)                   
                     | (sales["Net Amount"]<10)]
```

Here is the config class (config.py):

```
class config:

    input_path = "/home/ram/Downloads/Data_Science/"
    exclude_list = ["SCRAP ","GFT","B-MART HOME APPLIANCES","4 ELECTRONICS & APPLIANCES","DISCOUNT CORNER","CASH CUSTOMER","CASH BILL","GIFT"]
```

And here is the main file(main.py):

```
from config import config
from Recency import recency
recency(config)
```

This config is a python file where I have defined a class(named config) with `exclude_list` and this is what I send to the function(recency) via a main program.The problem here is I have included 8 items in the excluded list and this might change n future. So I might need to make changes to `recency function`(receny.py), such that when  create another `config` file which contains more (or less) than 8 items in excluded list,I will be able to use the same recency function to get df_exclude.What possible ways I can do this in python?

If anything is not clear in this question,please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative answer I would create a list for each variable to apply filter on:

```
class config:

    input_path = "/home/ram/Downloads/Data_Science/"
    exclude_product_list = ["SCRAP ","GFT"]
    exclude_customer_list = ["B-MART HOME APPLIANCES","4 ELECTRONICS & APPLIANCES","DISCOUNT CORNER","CASH CUSTOMER","CASH BILL"]
    exclude_remarks_list = ["GIFT"]
```

And then, in the recency function I would collapse each list into a string to filter:

```
def recency(config):

    # collapse values
    product_excludes = '|'.join(config.exclude_product_list)
    customer_excludes = '|'.join(config.exclude_customer_list)
    remarks_excludes = '|'.join(config.exclude_remarks_list)

    sales = pd.read_excel(config.input_path + "klm sales UPD.xlsx")


    df_exclude = sales[(sales["Product"].str.contains(product_excludes)==True)
                     | (sales["Customer"].str.contains(customer_excludes)==True)
                     | (sales["Remarks"].str.contains(remarks_excludes)== True)                   
                     | (sales["Net Amount"]<10)]
```

This way you cloud feed and custom each list to filter in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would collapse the blocks of 'or' statements by variable:

```
def recency(config):
    i = config.exclude_list

    sales = pd.read_excel(config.input_path + "klm sales UPD.xlsx")


    df_exclude = sales[(sales["Product"].str.contains(i[0] + '|' i[1])==True)
                     | (sales["Customer"].str.contains(i[2] + '|' + i[3] + '|' + i[4] + '|' + i[5] + '|' + i[6])==True)
                     | (sales["Remarks"].str.contains(i[7])== True)                   
                     | (sales["Net Amount"]<10)]
```

Comment: You are welcome. I would create a list of strings for each variable you want to apply excludes on (exclude_product_list, exclude_customer_list, etc.), and then I would collapse each list using the pattern 'string' + '|' + 'string' and use the result string in the corresponding .contains() method. Let me know if you understand what I meant and please upvote my answer in case this question is solved for other users

Comment: The other one,was quite good,please  give the above one as alternate answer. :)

Comment: Sure, I just added this alternative solution. Please, up-vote each answer if you found them useful. thanks to you RAM.